# Using JQ and curl to get list of all ID's that have a certain type

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

Been spending hours attempting to get this working.

So https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json contains every single version of the game ever made.

I want to get a list of all IDs with a certain type, so I want to only get the ID's of releases with the type "release", I don't want any of the "snapshots".

I managed to get a list without filtering the type, but I can't work out how to filter the type.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter array elements in `jq` using [select](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example28):

```
curl 'https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/game/version_manifest.json' |
   jq '.versions[] | select(.type == "release") | .id'
```